# What is the difference between (define (deriv-squared f ) (proc (deriv f))) and (define deriv-squared (proc deriv))?

Tags: scheme, racket, procedure

The code in my homework works without error:

```
(define (deriv-squared f)
(square-a-procedure (deriv f)))
```

But when I define it as below, it doesn't evaluate and says: "deriv as undefined" even I define it. What is the difference between two definitions?

```
(define deriv-squared (square-a-procedure deriv))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable needs to have a binding before it it is referenced (used).

If you have

```
(define deriv-squared (square-a-procedure deriv))
```

then `(square-a-procedure deriv)` is evaluated and the resulting value
is given the name `deriv-squared`. During the evaluation of `(square-a-procedure deriv)` the value of `deriv` is looked up. Therefore: the definition of `deriv` must be placed before the definition of `deriv-squared`.

(My guess is that you have placed the definition of `deriv` further down in the source file.)

Now why did your first definition work?

```
(define (deriv-squared f) (square-a-procedure (deriv f)))
```

This is short for:

```
(define deriv-squared 
   (lambda (f) 
      (square-a-procedure (deriv f))))
```

Here the `(lambda (f) (square-a-procedure (deriv f))))` evaluated to a procedure.
But `deriv` is not referenced until the procedure is used. So if `deriv` is defined before you use `deriv-squared` everything works fine.